# Editing the java .form xml

Tags: java, xml, forms, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ I made a .form file so I could make use of its form designer, I found that right-clicking in the designer shows the option to view the form source, which shows the xml that holds the form properties. However this view is read-only and does not allow editing, is there a way to do the editing in IntelliJ or should I always open the .form file in notepad to edit this?

Coming from Visual studio I expected the form xml to be as editable as the XAML.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to edit the form .xml file manually? If you don't want to use a visual designer, you should build your UIs as regular Java code.

Comment: I think the biggest advantage is that you can immediately see the result of my changes in the designer window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike XAML files, IntelliJ IDEA forms were not designed to be edited manually, so IntelliJ IDEA does not provide any support for working with .form files as plain text.